# Swift4. Dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, словари, swift4

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Я хочу чтобы текст, который пишется в `UITextView` при нажатии кнопки, на следующей странице трансформировался в текст уже видоизмененный, исходя из заданного словаря.

Например:

```
var hiraganaDictionary = [
     "a":"あ", "i":"い", "u":"う", "e":"え", "o":"お"
     "ka":"か", "ki":"き", "ku":"く", "ke":"け", "ko":"こ"]
```

Т.е, если происходит совпадение, то меняется буква или слог на заданное значение.

Необходимо чтоб сначала менялся слог, например "ka", а если такого слога в тексте нет, то просто на букву "a", если она тоже конечно есть.
Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: Как вы пытались решить эту задачу?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Swift. Трансформация текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953112/swift-%d0%a2%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk был вариант  `let str1 = "Hello" // строка из UITextView
let str2 = str1.reduce(into: "") {

    $0 += (hiraganaDictionary["\($1)"] ?? "\($1)")

} // строка для отображения на следующем экране
print(str2)`  
 Но текст трансформируется только по ключам где одна гласная буква и все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изящного решения к сожалению я не смог придумать, т.к. reduce позволяет делать перебор только по одному элементу.
Но вот такой алгоритм работает.

```
let hiraganaDictionary = [
 "a":"あ", "i":"い", "u":"う", "e":"え", "o":"お"
 "ka":"か", "ki":"き", "ku":"く", "ke":"け", "ko":"こ"]
let startString = "Hello ka"
var result = ""
var i = 0
while i < startString.count {
    var successAdd = false
    if i + 1 < startString.count {
        let indexStart = String.Index(encodedOffset: i)
        let indexEnd = String.Index(encodedOffset: i + 1)
        let s = String(startString[indexStart]) + String(startString[indexEnd])
        if let s2 = hiraganaDictionary[s] {
            result += s2
            i += 1
            successAdd = true
        }
    }
    if !successAdd {
        let index = String.Index(encodedOffset: i)
        let s = String(startString[index])
        result += hiraganaDictionary[s] ?? s
    }
    i += 1
}
print(result) // Hえllお か
```

Алгоритм можно сделать читабельнее, если добавить в String расширение позволяющее получать часть строки через Int индекс.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо. Все работает!